# comet, cometd, twisted, and websync

Tags: ajax, iis, comet, push

I am confused about comet, cometd, twisted, and websync.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comet is the technology itself (=allows to get and send requests from JS asyncroniously without very little overhead).

Cometd/twisted/Websync are specific implementations, applications which serve requests through comet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to BarsMonster's answer;
Comet Ajax(Reverse Ajax) refers to an Ajax design pattern that uses long-lived HTTP connections to enable low-latency communication between a web server and a browser. (Wikipedia 2010)

Some of the reliable implementations are;

- [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/) (Direct Web Remoting - Java )
- [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com) ( PokeIn Reverse (Comet) Ajax Library - .Net & Mono )